# How to use URL params in Facebook ad

Tags: facebook, google-ads-api

I have searched a lot and found these links:
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732

Facebook clearly says with "Get install of your app" objective, we cannot track URL params.
So I used "Send people to your website" objective as suggested here:
https://megalytic.com/blog/how-to-track-facebook-advertising-campaigns-in-google-analytics

But when I submit my URL (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blackbuck.sme&referrer=utm_source%3Dfb%26utm_medium%3Dbanner%26utm_content%3Dsmev1%26utm_campaign%3Dsmev1) to URL to promote of FB, I get following error:

**A website url outside of facebook is required for this objective**

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I have the same problem, any updates?

Comment: I have replied my comment as answer!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem.

**What I found:**
Basically Facebook doesnt allow app adv tracking to be used with tracking params. So as soon as facebook detects the link that you are sharing is app URL it will ask you to use "Get install of your app" objective.
In this objective there is no scope for URL params tracking. You will end up forcing yourself to use Facebook Analytics SDK inside your app to do this.

**Solution:**
Trick Facebook code to think link you are sharing in "Send people to your website" objective is not a app link by wrapping it using Tiny URL :)
Do note that I tried bitly but that didnt work. Facebook was able to figure out it was app link. I think it has to do with way in which bitly forwards link.
Caution: Facebook might one day fix this and detect app links from Tiny url too. Permanent solution is to have your own website links with custom params which ultimately redirects to app store

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have a domain or subdomain that is lying unused, you can point that to https://clpt.in and use that as your own link shortener for free.

P.S.: I am part of the team that built it